# Passing blank string as report parameter BIRT

Tags: java, report, birt, birt-emitter

I am using BIRT 4.3 in my Java application.

I am passing report parameters from a Java class to BIRT, and then I am displaying those parameters in the final(output) report.

If a value I am passing is `null`, then I want to pass blank string `""` as report parameter like this

```
map.put("NAME", salesLocBean.getName() == null ? "" : salesLocBean.getName().toUpperCase());
```

But BIRT does not seem to like that, some times it complaints that X parameter is blank and sometimes it runs fine but screws up the UI.

I have tried passing string with spaces like this '" "' but BIRT treats them as blank strings.

So how can I pass blank String `""` as report parameter to BIRT.

Comment: I can't be of any help with Java, but if you put it into BIRT with a string value like "changeMe" you could use a computed column in your data set to convert "changeMe" to what ever you want.

Comment: @JamesJenkins can I convert it to blank?

Comment: You can set the value of a computed column to pretty much anything you can write in JavaScript, but nothing between quotes "" should meet your need.

Comment: @JamesJenkins,  I am passing the value from java so I can't pass nothing

Comment: Pass "changeMe" to BIRT, then when it gets there convert it to ""

Comment: @JamesJenkins I think, I have a solution, can you tell me how can I change the font color of a report parameter (displayed on the page), in it's `onRender` script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could set the parameter to a `"changeMe"` value und replace it with an empty String `""` on the place where it is displayed in the report if it has the `"changeMe"` value. [Compare my answer to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36084594/how-to-display-another-value-if-the-column-is-null/36182210#36182210). You can just leave the field for the displayed value blank.